# Get rid of house logo and make ask question stand out

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Title says it all.  I think the logo is just too heavy for this style of a site.  Keep it simple with just the text Home Improvement.

Also make "Ask Question" stand out, it was difficult for me to post a question because I kept looking for a button or something sticking out and it just blended too much with the other links:

[image]

On the main site, the footer area has a white solid border around all the items.   This border is not necessary and adds to the site.  Feel free to remove that as well!

Answer (score 4):

We went to a lot of trouble to get our house back after the new profile changes went in. I'd hate to see it go.

I agree with you about making the "Ask Question" link stand out more.